# pthread_cleanup_push function get a bus error on Mac OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, pthreads

I want to run a example program about "**pthread**", and I can run it on Linux, but get a bus erron on Mac.

The program get from book "**Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment**" chapter 11.6 **p365**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void
cleanup(void *arg)
{
    printf("cleanup: %s\n", (char *)arg);
}

void *
thr_fn1(void *arg)
{
    printf("thread 1 start\n");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, "thread 1 first handler");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, "thread 1 second handler");

    printf("thread 1 push complete\n");

    if (arg)
        {
            return ((void *)1);
        }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    return ((void *)1);
}

void *
thr_fn2(void *arg)
{
    printf("thread 2 start\n");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, "thread 2 first handler");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, "thread 2 second handler");
    printf("thread 2 push complete\n");

    if (arg)
        {
            pthread_exit((void *)2);
        }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    pthread_exit((void *)2);
}

int
main(void)
{
    int           err;
    pthread_t     tid1, tid2;
    void          *tret;

    err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thr_fn1, (void *)1);
    if (err != 0)
        {
            printf("can't create thread 1: %s\n", strerror(err));
            return -1;
        }

    err = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thr_fn2, (void *)2);
    if (err != 0)
        {
            printf("can't create thread 2: %s\n", strerror(err));
            return -1;
        }

    err = pthread_join(tid1, &tret);
    if (err != 0)
        {
            printf("can't join with thread 1: %s\n", strerror(err));
            return -1;
        }
    printf("thread 1 exit code %d\n", (int)tret);

    err = pthread_join(tid2, &tret);
    if (err != 0)
        {
            printf("can't join with thread 2: %s\n", strerror(err));
            return -1;
        }
    printf("thread 2 exit code %d\n", (int)tret);

    return 0;
}
```

I can run it on Linux:

```
$ uname
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.14.4-200.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 13 13:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ./pthread_cleanup
thread 2 start
thread 2 push complete
cleanup: thread 2 second handler
cleanup: thread 2 first handler
thread 1 start
thread 1 push complete
thread 1 exit code 1
thread 2 exit code 2
```

But I get a "Bus err:10" on Mac:

```
$ uname -s -r -v -m -i -o
Darwin 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 MacBookPro11,1 Darwin

$ ./pthread_cleanup
thread 1 start
thread 2 start
thread 1 push complete
thread 2 push complete
cleanup: thread 2 second handler
Bus error: 10
```

Use "lldb" debug it:

```
$ lldb pthread_cleanup
(lldb) target create "pthread_cleanup"
Current executable set to 'pthread_cleanup' (x86_64).

(lldb) run
Process 19696 launched: '/path/to/pthread_cleanup' (x86_64)
thread 1 start
thread 2 start
thread 1 push complete
thread 2 push complete
Process 19696 stopped
* thread #2: tid = 0x3bc9eb, 0x00000001000b6000, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1000b6000)
    frame #0: 0x00000001000b6000
-> 0x1000b6000:  pushq  %rdx
   0x1000b6002:  pushq  %rsp
   0x1000b6004:  addb   %al, (%rax)
   0x1000b6006:  addb   %al, (%rax)
```

I think there are some differents between Mac and Linux platform.

Please give me some suggestions, so I can get a idea for next step.

Thx!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421688/pthread-cleanup-pop-with-argument-0?rq=1 I found the answer in this link. use `pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thr_fn2, (void *)0);` not `(void *)2);`

Comment: I will close that as a dupliate. So this is code from a book? What a shame. Anyhow, this casting integers into `void*` for the return of thread functions is really a bad habit of many.